# Set ASP DropDownList to SharePoint List Items

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-addin, office-365, asp.net

This one is probably really simple and I am missing something, I am creating an app dev model for SharePoint online and I currently have a ASP.NET DropDownList that I want to populate with items from within SharePoint.

I have got a list called "currency" within the host web and I have managed to retrieve all of these list items using some JavaScript, I now want to put these list items inside of the ASP.NET dropdown but I cant seem to get it wowrking.

I so far have the following code:

**.net dropdown:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="currencyDropDown" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function successHandler() {
        console.log("Success");
        var listItemInfo = '';
        var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
        while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
            console.log(oListItem.get_item('Title'));
            $("#currencyDropDown").val(oListItem.get_item('Title'));

        }
```

I have tried a few different solutions to set the dropdown but so far none of them appear to have worked.

I would greatly appreciate any help that I can be given with this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the HTML

```
<select>
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
 <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
 <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

So you have to **append** the OPTION DOM elements

Comment: +1 for putting the "Swedish" brands first ;)

Comment: Singular... Saab Automobile was aquired by Spyker (dutch) and then sold to the chinese

Comment: And now they do not exist. Volvo is now Chinese but developed in Sweden ;)

Comment: Thanks @DannyEngelman this really helped.

In the end I put what I was getting from the SharePoint list into an Array and using a for loop appended each item:

`var array = [oListItem.get_item('Title')];

                for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.value = array[i];
                    option.text = array[i];
                    var select = document.getElementById("currencyDropdown");
                    select.appendChild(option);`

Comment: If the question was answered, please press the Answer button, keeps No-Answers hunters and everyone else on StackOverflow happy.